# Openerp employee consultant contract management

Tags: odoo

I have been planning to manage a consultant employee contract in Openerp. I want to record all details of the employee which is being hired by the consultant. Including starting date , ending date , wages , working hours . How can I be able to do this .

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use hr_contract module for this and link it consultant. After installing hr_contract, It will allow you to create a contract for particular employee which is including Wage, Working Hours, Start Date, End date, etc. So you can link your employee being hired by the consultant with contract and use it.